# My program is often a deadlock,I don't know why,If I used coredata

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

When I was in use coredata multiple entities at the same time the request data will cause this phenomenon?
I couldn't find the reason, want to ask whether this reason

The following method is one of my program, there are two similar methods, they may at the same time, the cause of the deadlock is this?

```
+ (NSArray*)getChat{
NSManagedObjectContext * managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
NSError * error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Chat" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastMessage" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];

[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSArray * FetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] copy];
return FetchResults;
}
```

Comment: Any code for more details?

Comment: I put the code in question Thank you for your

Comment: Baaaaad Design: [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; Show the other method that runs at the same time and please show the code that calls these methods.

Comment: Deadlock issue is all about threading. You need to provide something  thread-related code informations. Are you running this method on two different threads at a time?

Comment: I see, thank you very, very, this method is called is not the same thread

Comment: It will helpful to see the way you call `getChat` in separate thread

Answer (score 0):

Managed objects themselves are not thread safe. If multiple threads access the `NSManagedObjectContext` this will cause a deadlock. Apple recommends on "[Concurrency with Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html)" to use the *thread confinement* pattern for work with concurrency in `Core Data`. Depending on your app, you can try:

1. Create a separate managed object context for each thread and share a single persistent store coordinator.
2. Or create a separate managed object context and persistent store coordinator for each thread.

And with multiple contexts you can pass objects between contexts by passing their `objectIDs` and fetching them in the other context.

You may want a more sophisticated approach using *Nested Contexts*. Here is a good article to help you with: [Multi-Context CoreData](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/).